# Problem in laravel vscode use wampserver and not xampp

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

when i install vscode by default php use WampServer and not xampp, in xampp php version is 7.3
i want to use this version and not php 5 
How i can change setting of vscode from php in wampserver to php in xampp?
note: i dont want to use wampserver ! only xampp.

[image: plz show this figure]

Comment: Why use xamp if you can use php artisan serve? Or better, laravel homestead?

Comment: i am new in laravel, by learning in youtube he use xampp.

Comment: Uninstall wamp, use only xampp. Probably it will solve your problem. You might need to update your windows path to point to php 7.3.